# Smarty, как скопировать шаблон?

Tags: php, smarty

Есть шаблон в папке `templates/imp/blocks/contacts_data.tpl`, который подключается на странице контактов.
Он подключается так:

```
          {block id ="contacts_data"}
          {assign var="contacts_data" value=1"}
          {block id ="contacts_data"}
```

Нужно создать похожий шаблон, к примеру `header_data.tpl`, который нужно подключить на всех страницах в шапке.
После создания `header_data.tpl` в той же папке и подключения его в шапке `head.tpl`:

```
            {block id ="header_data"}
            {assign var="header_data" value="1"}
            {block id ="header_data"}
```

этот новый шаблон не подключается.
Подскажите, как правильно подключить новый шаблон?

**P.S.**
В smarty плохо разбираюсь.
В шаблоне `contacts_data.tpl` используются такие переменные:

```
{section name=i loop=$items}
    <span>{$items[i].name}</span>
```

в новом шаблоне `header_data.tpl` эти переменные ничего не отображают.
Подскажите, как правильно это настроить, чтобы переменные в новом шаблоне работали?
Начало кода `contacts_data.tpl`

```
{if $parent.contacts_data=="1"}  
    код
```

В новом шаблоне сделал так:

```
{if $parent.header_data=="1"}
    код
```

**P.S.**   добавил еще к вопросу.
Подключаю шаблон так как показано ниже, подскажите, как теперь вывести все переменные, которые выводятся в шаблоне contacts_data?
сейчас эти переменные ничего не выводят, но разметка нового шаблона есть.
Нужно немного изменить разметку шаблона contacts_data

```
{include file="header_data.tpl"}
```

это условие убрал, все равно не работают переменные

```
{if $parent.header_data=="1"}
```

Comment: у меня почему то некоторое сомнение, что это подключается так, как вы думаете. Во первых, фактически `block` это не прямое подключение шаблона, а замена блока в родительском шаблоне при их наследовании. Этот тэг `block` должен иметь атрибут `name` которого  у вас почему то нет, а вот `id` это что-то левое. Сама конструкция `block` вроде появилась в версии 3, но почему-то соседствует у вас с устаревшим `assign`. Третья строка в первом куске кода, почему то такая же как первая, хотя должна бы быть закрывающим тэгом. Имхо, приведенный вами код, вообще ничего не делает.

Comment: возможно, это реализация какого-то плагина для смарти 2.

Comment: А чтобы добавить шаблон в шапку, в нужном месте впишите `{include "header_data.tpl"}` (с путем к файлу при необходимости), либо `{include file="..."}` для версии 2.

Comment: не мудрите. что у вас в шаблоне, который вставить хотите ? у вас старый и новый шаблон вообще связаны как то? если да, то пишите что и как связано. если это вообще разные шаблоны с разными данными, то зачем вы вообще смотрите на подключение шаблона контактов

Comment: @teran, мне нужно в шапку добавить шаблон, похожий на `contacts_data`. Но в `contacts_data` нужно кое-что удалить из разметки.

Comment: @teran, обновил вопрос. подскажите плз

Comment: данные для вашего шаблона контактов могли подкгружаться только на странице контактов (что логично) поэтому не понятно, почему вы ожидаете их увидеть на других страницах.

Answer (score 1):

> который нужно подключить на всех страницах в шапке.

для этих целей в нужном месте шапки используйте конструкцию [`{include}`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl)

Например,

```
{include "header_data.tpl"}
```

для старых версий смарти

```
{include file="header_data.tpl"}
```

Comment: обновил вопрос, подскажите плз. Да, это старая версия smarty